# Implementing undo action in a Javascript SPA

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, single-page-application

I am working on a project in Backbone and I have created a model (Todo) and a View (TodoView).
 I have given the user the option to edit a Todo by clicking on an edit button.

Now, I want to give the user the option to undo an edit. For example, when the user has clicked the edit button, edited the title, then edited the description and made several random changes, and now, he/she wants to go back to the state of before editing.

For this, I want to create a clone of the model inside the view (upon entering edit mode) and when the user click the cancel/undo button, reset the model to the data in cloned one.

I wonder if this is a good way to implement this functionality and if you guys have better ways to do it?

Thanks.

Comment: How many steps can the user undo? Backbone models already maintain a previousAttributes to facilitate a one-step-back state if this is what you're looking for.

Comment: They can go back one step.